# Extend and forward fill numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to duplicate each line of an array N times. Is there a quick way to do so?

Example (N=3):

```
# INPUT
a=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
# OUTPUT 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: "duplicate", not "multiply", perhaps?

Comment: Indeed. I edited my phrasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
np.repeat(a,3,axis=0)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Note that this is much faster then the other method.

```
N=100
%timeit np.repeat(a,N,axis=0)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.6 us per loop

%timeit rows, cols = a.shape;b=np.hstack(N*(a,));b.reshape(N*rows, cols)
1000 loops, best of 3: 257 us per loop

N=100000
%timeit np.repeat(a,N,axis=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.93 ms per loop

%timeit rows, cols = a.shape;b=np.hstack(N*(a,));b.reshape(N*rows, cols)
1 loops, best of 3: 245 ms per loop
```

Also [`np.tile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html#numpy.tile) is useful in similar situations.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> N = 3
>>> rows, cols = a.shape
>>> b=np.hstack(N*(a,))
>>> b
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8]])
>>> b.reshape(N*rows, cols)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: Awesome, but what about big N. If i have N=1000 is it possible to generate such a tuple (a,a,a,...) automatically?